# Force on cross sectional area

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics

[image]

From the previous post i made, i learnt that forces are usually apppied on areas. Now let's take a cross sectional area $A$. Forces as stated are applied over this whole area. We know pressure is force applied per unit area. So by definition it would be $P=\frac{F}{A}$. But here the forces which are acting on the cross sectional area are all same. I mean the same magnitude of forces are being applied on the area. So even if we take a unit area,that same force $F$ is being applied there,but by definition of pressure the force applied on a unit area should be $\frac{F}{A}$ whereas wherever we look at(no matter how large the area is),the same force $F$ is being applied. This is really contradictory(i know i am surely being wrong but i need to know where).

Or are the forces $F$ all added?I mean for example let's suppose $10$ vectors $F$ are being applied on area $A$. In that case for a unit area,obviously the number of vectors will be less than $10$,let's say $5$ (even though the magnitude is still same). Then will we take total force on $A$ as $10\times F$ and the unit area as $5\times F$? I am really confused.

Comment: Would like to clarify on my deleted answer that when I said F, i meant P integrated about the area to find the total force. however, Imagine I have a 2 by 2 grid, On each of these squares there is a force "F" acting on it, Clearly the pressure of a unit square, is the total force on that square divided by the area, Which would be F/1 = F Now if I take the full 2 by 2 grid, I would say that the total force is (4 * F) divided by the area (4) . Which is just F This is the same for both cases. The total force on a larger square would be greater, but the area would increase in proportion

Comment: So you mean the $4$ vectors of magnitude $F$ that i have drawn,i will add them up?The total force will then be $4F$. But then again,infinite number of forces(vectors) may act on a surface,does that mean infinite amount of force(magnitude) acts on that surface?This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: IF, an infinite number of "force" elements act on a surface, then the total force may not nesseserily be infinite, as each force could be "infinitely small"  Which is what my first answer was trying to say, taking pressure BY DEFINITION to be the force per unit area, If i want to have a total force of N newtons acting on my surface, such that the force is evenly distributed about the surface,

Comment: Then the pressure( Or force density) would be N/A, thus the infinitesimal amount of force acting on a DA element, DF = (N/A) da, Integrating this would then produce a finite F

Comment: Imagine a weight being attached to a cylindrical wire,here the force $mg$ is being applied on the circular cross sectional area. Here a LOT of vectors of magnitude $mg$ are being applied on the circular area not  infinitesimal vectors.

Comment: No, the SUM of all of the vectors would be mg. By defintion of the TOTAL force being mg,

Comment: Thanks,now kindly take a look at my picture if we say total force $mg$ is being applied,does that mean all the forces i drew are components of $mg$?But the components are parallel,don't we need to act components head to tail for getting the whole vector?Here components are parallel.

Comment: If a total force of N newtons is applied on a body, In reality, each force is due to the individual particles, which each particle OBVIOUSLY doesnt contribute a force of N newtons, it will be a fraction of N such that the total contribution is N. On  your diagram, if a TOTAL force on your square is MG, Then by your diagram atleast, then each force component you have drawn would be MG/4 such that the sum is MG

Comment: Parallel vectors add like any other vectors?

Comment: $P = F/A$ is only the AVERAGE pressure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your diagram, there are four distinct, for want of a better term, "pressure points", one for each of the four applied forces. If each of the forces were actually acting at a point, the pressure exerted by each force would be infinite because a "point" has zero area.

In reality, all forces act on some finite area, even if small. For pressure due to physical contact forces, you need to divide the force by the area over which the contact force is acting. For example, if a book is placed on a table it exerts a pressure at the surface of the table equal to its weight divided by the area of contact with the table, not the total area of the table.

On the other hand, if we are interested in the mechanical stresses and deformation within a deformable material under the area A due to the four forces, they will be distributed in some fashion throughout the material below the surface, due to the lateral stresses produced by the local forces, being a maximum directly below the application areas, dropping to a minimum between the application areas.

> could you verify if what jensen paull in his last comment about 4
> was right in reply to my post? Also as you mentioned,since force can't
> act on a point, could you please illustrate with a picture where a
> single force is being on an area?That would clear my doubts.

I agree with @jensen paull that if the total force applied to the area A is $Mg$ then the force applied at each of the four "locations" is $Mg/4$, provided that the total force is evenly distributed to the four locations.

I can't say if that answered your post because, with statements like,  "let's suppose 10 vectors  are being applied on area $A$", it appears you continue to confuse the depiction of forces by vectors, which are simply geometric objects, with the actual forces themselves. I believe that, in turn, has you confused about the pressures associated with forces.

But you have asked me to illustrate the concepts with a picture, so I will. Your diagram shows four vectors which I assume are intended to depict four forces that are applied to four locations within the area $A$. A physical example are the forces that the four legs of the table in the figure below, with a book on top, would exert on the floor below. The figure shows the forces the book applies to the table, and the book plus table applies to the floor, as well as the reaction $R$ forces of the table and floor.

If the four legs are symmetrically located around the center of mass of the book, $m$ plus the mass of the table $M$ (which includes the legs), the magnitude of the force $F_{B+T}$ exerted by each leg would be

$$F_{B+T}=\frac{(m+M)g}{4}$$

Now, the magnitude of the pressure that each leg exerts on the floor is equal to the force exerted by each leg divided by the *surface area of contact* between the leg and the floor,  which would be the cross sectional area $a_{L}$ of a leg with a flat bottom, or

$$P_{B+T}=\frac{(m+M)g}{4a_{L}}$$

I have emphasized "surface area of contact" because in your diagram that is only the part of A that is in contact with the legs, not the entire floor area A. You can think of the surface area of contact as the "footprint" of the legs on the floor.

Now let's turn our attention to the book on top of the table. It exerts a pressure on the table

$$P=\frac{mg}{a_{B}}$$

Where $a_{B}$ is the area of contact between the book and the table, not the total surface area of the table.

For both the book and the table leg the force that is applied is in actuality distributed over the surface area of contact.

For example, let the density ($N/m^3$) of the book be $\rho$. An infinitesimal volume of the book of $dV=(dl)(dw)(dh)$ where $dl,dw,dh$ are infinitesimal amounts of length, width, and height of the book, will exert a infinitesimal amount of force  on the table of

$$dF_{B}=g\rho dV$$

To get the total force exerted by the book on the table we integrate (sum up) all the infinitesimal forces

$$F_{B}=\int_V dF_{B}=\int_V g\rho dV$$

if the density of the book is uniform (constant) over its volume we have

$$F_{B}=\rho g \int_V dV=\rho V g=mg$$

The same would apply to each leg, with the total mass being $m+M$.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the kind answer,a question,could you verify if what jensen paull in his last comment about $\frac{mg}{4}$ was right in reply to my post? Also as you mentioned,since force can't act on a point,coul you please illustrate with a picture where a single force is being on an area?That would clear my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a pressure that varies by location $P(x,y)$, then the total force applied is

$$ F = \iint P(x,y)\,{\rm d}A$$

and the total area of course being $A = \iint {\rm d}A$ means that the *average* pressure is

$$ P_{\rm ave} = \frac{F}{A} = \frac{ \iint P {\rm d}A } { \iint {\rm d}A } $$

In terms of forces acting, it is the same to say the average pressure is acting on the entire area, or the actual pressure distribution acts on the area. There is no distinction between these two statements.

$$ F = P_{\rm ave}\,A = \iint P {\rm d}A $$

But it makes a whole lot of difference when considering the deflection this pressure causes on the surface of the material. A concentrated pressure distribution is going to create a dimple, whereas a distributed average pressure is going to have a more gentle depression.

If you consider a single force acting on a point, then the pressure is infinite, and the deflection is also infinite at that point (a singularity in mechanics). This is why we always need to spread out forces over an area to model real physical phenomena.

This is also the reason contact mechanics are non-linear as the higher the contact forces, the larger the contact area becomes but not proportionally. This causes all sorts of complex behavior in the area of contact mechanics.

---

PS. The deflection at the center of a contact patch, with pressure $P(x,y)$ where $x$, %y% are measured from the center is found by

$$ \delta = \tfrac{1-\nu^2}{E} \iint \tfrac{P(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \,{\rm d}A $$

This is the so called Businessq relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Normally there is an external force applied to object, a rod for example, of which it is being analized the situation in some cross section. This force is finite and well defined, (by a weight hanging below for example).

All the cross section supports the external force, so it is a distributed force over that area. If for any reason, we want to know the force acting on a small area $\Delta A$ of the section, it is $F_{\Delta A} = P\Delta A$. I suppose here that $P$ is constant over the section.

Answer (score 0):

In general, on each tiny segment of a surface, there can be a small resultant force (which may have normal and frictional components).  The total force on the surface will be the vector sum of these resultants.